# Is a columnstore index appropriate when all columns are (mostly) unique?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, columnstore, index-design

I have a longish table ( 60M rows ) where there are only 7 columns. One is a unique ID, two are datetimes, and two are notes and descriptions.

There the notes and descriptions are very regular, except for a tag at the end of the text. So, they're technically unique. I can't take that unique tag out as the tags are signatures and these notes and descriptions are legal documents.

If it wasn't for those tags, they'd be 95% from stock descriptions - maybe 15 variations.

These descriptions are up to 8K chars long. I long for some reasonable compression, and am considering a clustered columnstore index to implement that compression, but I'm unclear as to whether the compression will even occur w/ these columns being tagged into uniqueness.

These descriptive columns comprise more than 90% of the row data.

So...rowstore indexing is appropriate for the 'key' column...but I'm wondering if I should define this after the clustered columnstore index.

Current:

```
create table dbo.SPECIMEN
(
  ID                        int not null,
  Specimen_Types            varchar(255) null,
  Collected_Date            datetime null,
  Received_Date             datetime null,
  Results                   varchar(4000) null,
  Notes                     varchar(max) null,
  Lab_Report_ID             int not null
)
go
create clustered index [SPECIMEN.ID.Lab_Report_ID.Fake.PrimaryKey]
on dbo.SPECIMEN(ID,Lab_Report_ID);
go
create index [SPECIMEN.Lab_Report_ID.Index]
on dbo.SPECIMEN(Lab_Report_ID);
```

...and I if I get good compression, I'd change the indexes this way:

```
go
create clustered columnstore index [SPECIMEN.CCI]
on dbo.SPECIMEN;
go
create index [SPECIMEN.ID.Lab_Report_ID.Fake.PrimaryKey]
on dbo.SPECIMEN(ID,Lab_Report_ID);
go
create index [SPECIMEN.Lab_Report_ID.Index]
on dbo.SPECIMEN(Lab_Report_ID);
```

Does this make sense? I have very little experience with columnstore indexing and don't want to step on my own foot.

BTW - fake primary key. It is supposed to be unique, but the app that populates the source data occasionally throws in a duplicate. This table is supposed to be an extract from that semi-stable source.

Comment: "if I get good compression", so test it.  Compression is all about tradeoffs, so without testing, it's just guessing.

Comment: I will...but it's expensive in this environment ...so just looking for preliminary guidance.

Comment: The guidance is:  we can't predict the effectiveness of columnstore here either, so get a test environment and test it.

Comment: You can use [sp_estimate_data_compression_savings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-estimate-data-compression-savings-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to get a rough idea for all different types of data compression options: NONE, ROW, PAGE, COLUMNSTORE, or COLUMNSTORE_ARCHIVE

Comment: Is that available for SQL 2016? I thought columnstore support was new in 2019.  EG https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/sql-server-2019-disappointment-sp_estimate_data_compression_savings/

Comment: @ErikDarling, thanks - that was helpful...didn't know if I'd get anything at all...and I apparently will.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - that sp is there in 2016, but not all parms are supported...but I got enough to take the plunge.

Comment: @DavidBrowne ah yeah, missed the 2016 tag. My bad!

Comment: Good advice here so far, just keep in mind some of the tradeoff of compression is generally additional CPU overhead. But I've found most times people aren't using 100% of their CPU 100% of the time, and depending on the type of compression, the amount of data, and the compression ratio achieved, the overhead is typically not much, so it's usually worth the tradeoff. Just something to be aware of.

Comment: Yep.  The uncompressed row format dates from the mid 1990s when CPU cores were like 90% slower.  So very CPU efficient, space-efficient not so much.

Comment: Well...will add a comment for those who come after...the schema presented is not appropriate for clustered columnstore indexing because of the varchar(max). I probed for data that is actually that wide...hoping I could redefine it to a narrower column. Nope...can't switch. Dang! Still...thanks everybody.